# Cannot get OpenCV working, I'm using CMake and C++

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

Here is the code

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

project ("Virtual_painter")

FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCV REQUIRED)


SET(SRC "Virtual_painter.cpp")
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${OpenvCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${OpenCV_LIB_DIR})

# Add source to this project's executable.
add_executable (Virtual_painter ${SRC})


# TODO: Add tests and install targets if needed.
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

Virtual_paint.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
using namespace cv;

int main()
{

    Mat color = imread("test.jpeg");

    imwrite("image", color);

    return 0;
}
```

The image is in the same directory by the way.

I keep getting this error

```
    [build] [1/1 100% :: 0.120] Linking CXX executable Virtual_painter.exe
[build] FAILED: Virtual_painter.exe 
[build] cmd.exe /C "cd . && D:\VIsualStudioIDE\VC\Tools\Llvm\bin\clang.exe -fuse-ld=lld-link -nostartfiles -nostdlib -g -Xclang -gcodeview -O0 -D_DEBUG -D_DLL -D_MT -Xclang --dependent-lib=msvcrtd -Xlinker /subsystem:console CMakeFiles/Virtual_painter.dir/Virtual_painter.cpp.obj -o Virtual_painter.exe -Xlinker /implib:Virtual_painter.lib -Xlinker /pdb:Virtual_painter.pdb -Xlinker /version:0.0   D:/OpenVC/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world451d.lib  D:/OpenVC/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world451d.lib  D:/OpenVC/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world451d.lib  D:/OpenVC/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world451d.lib  D:/OpenVC/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world451d.lib  D:/OpenVC/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world451d.lib  D:/OpenVC/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world451d.lib  D:/OpenVC/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world451d.lib  D:/OpenVC/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world451d.lib  D:/OpenVC/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world451d.lib  D:/OpenVC/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world451d.lib  D:/OpenVC/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world451d.lib  D:/OpenVC/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world451d.lib  D:/OpenVC/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world451d.lib  D:/OpenVC/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world451d.lib  D:/OpenVC/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world451d.lib  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 -loldnames && cd ."
[build] lld-link: error: undefined symbol: class cv::Mat __cdecl cv::imread(class std::basic_string<char, struct std::char_traits<char>, class std::allocator<char>> const &, int)
[build] >>> referenced by D:\Projects\c++\Virtual_painter\Virtual_painter.cpp:14
[build] >>>               CMakeFiles/Virtual_painter.dir/Virtual_painter.cpp.obj:(_main)
[build] 
[build] lld-link: error: undefined symbol: bool __cdecl cv::imwrite(class std::basic_string<char, struct std::char_traits<char>, class std::allocator<char>> const &, class cv::debug_build_guard::_InputArray const &, class std::vector<int, class std::allocator<int>> const &)
[build] >>> referenced by D:\Projects\c++\Virtual_painter\Virtual_painter.cpp:16
[build] >>>               CMakeFiles/Virtual_painter.dir/Virtual_painter.cpp.obj:(_main)
[build] 
[build] lld-link: error: undefined symbol: public: __thiscall cv::Mat::~Mat(void)
[build] >>> referenced by D:\Projects\c++\Virtual_painter\Virtual_painter.cpp:19
[build] >>>               CMakeFiles/Virtual_painter.dir/Virtual_painter.cpp.obj:(_main)
[build] >>> referenced by D:\Projects\c++\Virtual_painter\Virtual_painter.cpp:19
[build] >>>               CMakeFiles/Virtual_painter.dir/Virtual_painter.cpp.obj:(?dtor$9@?0?main@4HA)
[build] clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
[build] ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
[build] Build finished with exit code 1
```

I don't know if it has something to do with the compiler, I highly doubt it but I'm open to any suggestion...

Comment: The linker command line contains `D:/OpenVC/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world451d.lib` **repeated** 16(!) times. Have you **manually** specify some variables, like `OpenCV_LIBS`, when **invoke** `cmake`?

Comment: I haven't specified any OpenCV_LIBS manually

Comment: What version of OpenCV are you using and how did you build / install it?

Comment: @AlexReinking I would say 4.5.1 given the filename...

Comment: I pointed the path of OpenCV to the PATH system variable